# Can log4net be set up so that one shared configuration XML file is used for many Windows Service projects?

Tags: c#, windows-services, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have several Windows Service projects that will be installed in the same domain. Each project has a reference to a company.core.common project where I place shared methods and properties for all of the Windows Service projects to use. I want to implement log4net as the logging solution for all of my Windows Service projects but I do not what to have to copy and paste the  sections of the XML configuration file to each Windows Service project's app.config or maintain multiple configuration files. For maintenance purposes, I want to only have one log4net configuration file for all services.

Is there a way to put the log4net configuration XML and perhaps instantiate the logger in the company.core.common project?

If so, then Since all of the Windows service projects have a reference to the core.common project, they would then be able to add a "using company.core.common" statement to their class files and then the methods in class would be able to write log messages to company.core.common.logger (where logger is the instance of the log4net log object in the company.core.common project)

My service projects will all be logging to an adonetAppender that writes to a SQL Server database for the root logger.

Comment: I didn't fully understand from reviewing the previously posted answers. The problem stemmed from the fact that I did not initially understand that DLL projects did not need to have their own log4net config file assignments. Putting the config file in the executable project that references the DLL was all that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can. You have to do two things:

1. Create a [symbolic link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) of your 'shared' app config section (log4net) in computer where your windows service is running.
2. Merge shared (log4net) from sym-linked file to your original file. See [how to provide configSource attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4464240/442470) to merge app config sections from another partial config file.